# How to Force "postgresql" to use Unique Index When Together Non-Unique Index

Tags: postgresql

I have a `select` query that uses two `indexes` (one of a `unique` index, one of a `non-unique` index).

They always use first index of the `where` clause. How can I force that query to use a unique index whether any `sequential`? My query create by `ORM`, I can't adjust `sequential`.

Answer (score 0):

You create a partial index from which you exclude the rows that do not satisfy the index unique values. 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/indexes-partial.html